# Create custom gradient in bootstrap 4 using SASS function theme-color-level

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I have setup Bootstrap 4 theme variables as follows:

```
// custom-theme.scss
$primary: green;
$secondary: purple;
```

Then custom variables like:

```
// custom-variables.scss
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";

$idi-primary-12: theme-color-level(primary, -12);
```

Then importing all as follows:

```
//main.scss,
@import "./bootstrap-theme";
@import "./custom-variables";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

This updates bootstrap classes like `btn-primary` and `text-secondary` AS EXPECTED (nice);

But the *custom variable* ($idi-primary-12) based on my **$primary** doesn't work. I was using the `theme-color-level` SASS function as given here in the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#functions).

When I use this in my component,

```
// myComponent.scss
@import "../custom-variables";

.myUserInfo {
    background-color: $idi-primary-12;
    color: color-yiq($idi-primary-12);
}
```

I get **BLUE** shade (which is the default in the **bootstrap/scss/variables.scss**). [Github source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/7da9729a62c1962865016282aea9e0f352b869e8/scss/_variables.scss#L69) instead of my override (**green** - as set above)

Question: How do I use theme-color-level function, to use my $primary (green) variable to generate a lighter version of that green? (and not the default blue).

Additional info:
[official documentation for SASS functions](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#functions)

1. `theme-color-level` uses `theme-color`
2. `theme-color` extracts from object `$theme-colors` by key (I am using **primary**)
3. `$theme-colors` **primary** key is set to `$primary` ([Github for $theme-colors](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/7da9729a62c1962865016282aea9e0f352b869e8/scss/_variables.scss#L82))
4. `$primary` is set to **blue** ([Github for $primary](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/7da9729a62c1962865016282aea9e0f352b869e8/scss/_variables.scss#L69))
5. This should have be overridden by my `$primary = green;` from *custom-theme.scss*. That is why btn-primary is working. (shown as green). But why isn't it using that same overridden variable to create my `$idi-primary-12` variable?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK **theme-color-level** function in Bootstrap will take 2 parameters, **color-name** from the theme in string (eg, 'primary', 'info') and **level** in number as shown below:

```
// Request a theme color level
@function theme-color-level($color-name: "primary", $level: 0) {
  $color: theme-color($color-name);
  $color-base: if($level > 0, $black, $white);
  $level: abs($level);

  @return mix($color-base, $color, $level * $theme-color-interval);
}
```

and if we want to use this function for some colors other then the theme colors (eg. 'primary'), maybe we can write another function for that, eg:

```
@function custom-color-level($color: pink, $level: 0) {
  $color-base: if($level > 0, $black, $white);
  $level: abs($level);

  @return mix($color-base, $color, $level * $theme-color-interval);
}
```

with this custom function, we can pass the first param as color (eg. #007bff, orange)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo, $primary instead of primary

```
$idi-primary-12: theme-color-level($primary, -12);
```

Comment: Actually **theme-color-level** takes a theme key, "primary", "success".. **$primary** holds a color value. :\

Answer (score 0):

**theme-color-level** surprisingly is not internally using the overridden $primary value. Instead it is taking the default $primary value (blue).

I was able to use other function, which directly works on my overridden **$primary** value.

```
// custom.scss
$primary: green;

darken($primary, 10% )
lighten($primary, 10% )
```

[Reference](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/controlling-color-with-sass-color-functions)